# .htaccess and session dont work like it should

Tags: .htaccess

in my site i'm using a sesssion. In my htaccess i have got rules like:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^-]+)/([^-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,NC,NS]
> RewriteRule ^([^-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,NS]
> ```

It's work perfect. When someone create a session from www address, there is a problem with session on non-www address. It doesn't work.
When i'm add a rule to redirect from non-www to www:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

first rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)/([^-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,NC,NS]
```

don't work and address looks like

```
index.php?page=link1&action=link2
```

What can I do in this case?

Thanks for help. Greetings

Comment: Put your `non-www` to `www` redirection rule at the top before other rules. It should be placed exectly below `RewriteEngine on` .

Comment: Nope. Still dont work like it should. address is still not hided.

Comment: It should work . Try clearing your browser cache .

Comment: yep. on incognito work perfect. thanks for help. cheers